# sendTransaction returning “insufficient funds” when the account has enough ether

Tags: web3js

I am trying to send a transaction to the Ropsten network, using Infura as the Web3 provider. My transaction is being rejected ("insufficient funds for gas * price + value") and I suspect the reason is that the message is not being properly signed.

This is my code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

let endpoint = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(endpoint));

private_key = "0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
address = "0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(private_key);

recipient = "0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: address,
    to: recipient,
    value: '10',
    gas: 50000,
}).then(function(receipt){
    console.log(receipt);
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I would try signing transaction on my end and then use `sendSignedTransaction` for sending transaction.

Comment: That worked. I think there might be a bug in web3 causing this.

Comment: Okay then. I'll post this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem with `sendTransaction` was because you didn't have any accounts imported in the web3 object so, `sendTransaction` was unable to sign it.
You can import a wallet in the web3 object with

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3Provider = new Web3(process.env.RPC_ENDPOINT);

// import wallet in the provider
web3Provider.eth.accounts.wallet.add(WALLET_KEY);
```

With your wallet imported, if you call `sendTransaction` and the `from` in the transaction data matches with the imported address, it will automatically sign the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I would try signing transaction on my end and then use `sendSignedTransaction` for sending transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async function signAndSendTransaction() {
    const options = {
        to : recipient,
        value: "10",
        gas: 21000
    };
    const signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, private_key);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that accounts APIs would be available while using infura?

Comment: @Ayushya: I'm pretty sure that this is a web3 provider-agnostic API.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple days trying to get web3's amazing send() function (call seems to work well enough) to work Robsten, Kovan, Ganache, nothing works with web3 at the moment!  On Kovan I get the Insufficient Funds error that OP reports. On Robsten I got the error:

`eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available`

On ganache, I got something about a missing `clientId` opcode.

What ended working was implementing `sendSignedTransaction`

Here's what I wrote in typescript, hope it saves you some time.

```
import TX from 'ethereumjs-tx'

public async sendRawTx(params: ISignedTxParams) {
  const web3 = await this.getOrInitializeWeb3()
  const from = this.accountAddress
  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from)
  const gasLimit = web3.utils.toHex(3000000)
  const gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(5 * 1e9) // 5 gwei
  const txParams = {
    from,
    nonce,
    gasLimit,
    gasPrice,
    to: params.to,
    value: params.value || 0,
    data: params.data,
  }
  const tx = new TX(txParams)
  tx.sign(new Buffer(this.accountPrivateKey!, 'hex'))
  const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
  console.log('serializedTx : ', serializedTx)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedTx.toString('hex')}`)
      .on('receipt', (r) => {
        console.log("Received Receipt", r)
        resolve(r)
      })
      .on('confirmation', console.log)
      .on('transactionHash', console.log)
      .on('error', reject)
  })
}


public async getOrInitializeWeb3(): Promise<Web3> {
  if (this.web3) {
    return this.web3
  }

  const httpProvider = new HttpProvider(this.web3ProviderArgs)
  this.web3 = new Web3(httpProvider)

  if (this.accountPrivateKey) {
    const account = this.web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(`0x${this.accountPrivateKey}`)
    if (account.address !== this.accountAddress) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid Eth crypto key pair`)
    }

    this.web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account)
    this.web3.defaultAccount = account.address
  }

  return this.web3
}

export interface ISignedTxParams {
  to: string,
  value: string,
  data: Buffer
}
```

Then you can call to the sendRawTx like this:

```
const data = contractInstance.methods.someFunc("Hello", 123).encodeABI()
await this.web3Service.sendRawTx({to: contractInstance.address, data})
```